# Parsing /proc/cpuinfo fails

Tags: rust

I am attempting to parse `/proc/cpuinfo` on Linux and am running into some trouble.

I'd like to return:

- model name
- cores
- siblings

I was wanting to return them as a struct but I'd be happy with anything that returned them all.

```
use std::{
    collections::HashMap,
    fmt,
    fs::File,
    io::{self, Read},
};

pub struct CPUInfo {
    pub model_name: String,
    pub cores: u16,
}

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum Error {
    UnsupportedSystem,
    //ExecFailed(io::Error),
    IO(io::Error),
    Unknown,
}

impl fmt::Display for Error {
    fn fmt(&self, fmt: &mut fmt::Formatter) -> fmt::Result {
        use self::Error::*;
        match *self {
            UnsupportedSystem => write!(fmt, "System is not supported"),
            //ExecFailed(ref e) => write!(fmt, "Execution failed: {}", e),
            IO(ref e) => write!(fmt, "IO error: {}", e),
            Unknown => write!(fmt, "An unknown error occurred"),
        }
    }
}

impl std::error::Error for Error {
    fn description(&self) -> &str {
        use self::Error::*;
        match *self {
            UnsupportedSystem => "unsupported system",
            //ExecFailed(_) => "execution failed",
            IO(_) => "io error",
            Unknown => "unknown error",
        }
    }

    fn cause(&self) -> Option<&std::error::Error> {
        use self::Error::*;
        match *self {
            UnsupportedSystem => None,
            //ExecFailed(ref e) => Some(e),
            IO(ref e) => Some(e),
            Unknown => None,
        }
    }
}

impl From<io::Error> for Error {
    fn from(e: io::Error) -> Error {
        Error::IO(e)
    }
}

pub fn get_cpu() -> Result<CPUInfo, Error> {
    if cfg!(target_os = "linux") {
        let mut s = String::new();
        File::open("/proc/cpuinfo")?.read_to_string(&mut s)?;
        let mut cpuinfo_hashmap = HashMap::new();
        for line in s.lines() {
            let mut split_line = line.split_whitespace();
            let label = split_line.next();
            let value = split_line.next();
            if value.is_some() && label.is_some() {
                let label = label.unwrap().split(':').nth(0).ok_or(Error::Unknown)?;
                let value = value.unwrap().to_string();
                cpuinfo_hashmap.insert(label, value.to_string());
            }
        }

        Ok(CPUInfo {
            model_name: {
                let m = cpuinfo_hashmap.get("model name").ok_or(Error::Unknown)?;
                m.to_string()
            },
            cores: {
                let c = cpuinfo_hashmap.get("siblings").ok_or(Error::Unknown)?;
                let cores: u16 = c.parse::<u16>().unwrap();
                cores
            },
        })
    } else {
        Err(Error::UnsupportedSystem)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let cpu = get_cpu().expect("error getting cpu");
    println!("CPU: {} {}", cpu.model_name, cpu.cores)
}
```

([Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff88e7d7a331f1c57c10498359a4222f))

This code fails:

```
thread 'main' panicked at 'error getting cpu: Unknown', libcore/result.rs:1009:5
note: Run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace.
```

Then someone on Reddit suggested using [derive_builder](https://crates.io/crates/derive_builder) so I tried:

```
pub fn cpu_info() -> Result<CPUInfo, Error> {
    let file = File::open("/proc/cpuinfo")?;
    let buf_reader = BufReader::new(file);
    let mut builder = &mut CPUInfoBuilder::default();

    for line in buf_reader.lines() {
        let line = line.unwrap();
        let kv: Vec<_> = line.splitn(2, ':').map(|s| s.trim()).collect();

        builder = match kv.as_slice() {
            ["model name", v] => builder.model_name(v.to_string()),
            ["cpu cores", v] => builder.cores(v.parse::<u16>().ok().ok_or(Error::Unknown)?),
            [_, _] => builder,
            [_] => builder,
            _ => unreachable!(),
        }
    }
    Ok(builder.build().expect("failed"))
}
```

Which also compiles and fails.

Comment: Please produce a [MCVE]. Specifically "fails" is a very poor diagnostic; a copy/paste of the output you get and how it differs from what you'd like would be a big improvement.

Comment: @loganfsmyth it's not a native Rust library, but a binding over a C library, it hasn't been updated for 3 years, and its website's domain is for sale. I'd say this crate should be avoided now.

Comment: May I suggest my own crate [cupid](https://docs.rs/cupid/0.6.1/cupid/) then? ^_^

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please review how to create a [MCVE] and then [edit] your question to include it. We cannot tell what crates, types, traits, fields, etc. are present in the code. Try to produce something that reproduces your error on the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org) or you can reproduce it in a brand new Cargo project. There are [Rust-specific MCVE tips](//stackoverflow.com/tags/rust/info) as well.

Comment: @mcarton Ha, I copied the link without looking close enough, meant to link to Shepmaster's

Comment: Hey, I'm trying to fix your code up. What error type are you using? Seems like a custom error because `std::error::Error` is not working and neither is `std::io::Error`.

Comment: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff88e7d7a331f1c57c10498359a4222f

Comment: I Apologize for my poor form everyone! This is my first post on stack overflow and I really appreciate how helpful you all have been. Cupid is a really cool crate, I had not heard of it before now. I see how I can get the name of the CPU but is there a way to get the number of physical and logical cores as well?

Answer (score 2):

Your code had a few problems with it. I hate to just rewrite a person's code for them, but some of the stuff you had going was just not going to work even after compilation succeeded. There are some pointers for you in the code below.

Here is code that builds the struct you expect, prints to a `HashMap` for debugging, and then prints the information in the struct for easy viewing:

```
use std::{
    fs::File,
    io::{BufRead, BufReader, Error, ErrorKind},
};

use hashbrown::HashMap;

fn main() {
    let cpu = get_cpu().unwrap();
    println!("{}{}", cpu.model_name, cpu.cores);
}

pub struct CPUInfo {
    pub model_name: String,
    pub cores: u16,
}

pub fn get_cpu() -> Result<CPUInfo, Error> {
    if cfg!(target_os = "linux") {
        let f = File::open("/proc/cpuinfo")?;
        let reader = BufReader::new(f);
        let mut cpuinfo_hashmap: HashMap<String, String> = HashMap::new();

        for line in reader.lines().take(20) {
            let line = line.unwrap();
            let mut split_line = line.split(':');
            let label = split_line.next();
            let value = split_line.next();
            if value.is_some() && label.is_some() {
                let label = label.unwrap().trim().to_string();
                let value = value.unwrap().trim().to_string();
                cpuinfo_hashmap.insert(label, value);
            }
        }

        println!("{:?}", cpuinfo_hashmap);

        Ok(CPUInfo {
            model_name: {
                let m = cpuinfo_hashmap
                    .get("model name")
                    .ok_or(Error::from(ErrorKind::InvalidData))?;
                m.clone()
            },
            cores: {
                let c = cpuinfo_hashmap
                    .get("siblings")
                    .ok_or(Error::from(ErrorKind::InvalidData))?;
                let cores: u16 = c.parse::<u16>().unwrap_or(0);
                cores
            },
        })
    } else {
        Err(Error::from(ErrorKind::Other))
    }
}
```

Problems with your code:

1. You didn't post your imports, which made it really hard for me
2. You can't `BufRead` a `String`, you need to `BufRead` the `File` directly
3. Your `line` variable needs to be unwrapped before use
4. Line needs to be unwrapped AND bound to a variable to prevent borrow-checking errors
5. You split the line on whitespace first, then again on the `":"` character, which gives you a `HashMap` with 20 entries that look like `"processor" : ":"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I see where I messed up. [This is what I was working with earlier btw.](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff88e7d7a331f1c57c10498359a4222f) Apologies for lack of specificity. This is my first time using stackoverflow.

Comment: Why go out of your way to use hashbrown? I doubt that the performance is going to matter in this case, it complicates understanding, and hashbrown is likely to be made into the standard library hashmap implementation anyway.

Comment: This code has its own small issues. Calling `next` multiple times without checking for `None` (and not fusing the iterator); needless `unwrap`s; maybe more.

Comment: [Some changes](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=81fb60d7019db39198f0368ea9613d1c).

Comment: So this is my first attempt trying to parse a file like this. Do you have any recommendation on how you personally would go about trying to parse this kind of file?

Comment: Some background on my goal here, I am trying to eventually make a program that does what neofetch does but in pure rust.

Comment: @Shepmaster my usual way of answering questions on here is to change as little of their code as possible when making it work, to help them learn. I used hasbrown because it appeared that that's what he was using. Also the same with the multiple `next` calls

Comment: @Shepmaster your changes are the way I would have implemented it, but his way works and it's a learning process :)

Comment: The multiple next calls is **incorrect** by the definition of the iterator trait though. What is returned after next return a none is not defined.